# extracting phrases from text file in java

Tags: java

i'm doing project on host based intrusion detection using ADFA-LD dataset ,now i'm doing feature extraction module. i constructed the phrase dictionary which consists of system call phrases of length 4. And now for feature extraction ,i need to compare the phrases with the new system call traces (following are some samples):

sys_clock_gettime   sys_poll    sys_poll    sys_clock_gettime   sys_poll    sys_poll
    sys_poll    sys_clock_gettime   sys_poll    sys_clock_gettime   sys_poll    sys_poll sys_poll   sys_poll    sys_poll    sys_poll    sys_poll    sys_poll    sys_socketcall.......

What i need is, how can i compare these phrases with the new traces. i'm doing in java.

my phrase dictionary:

sys_socketcall-sys_poll-sys_clock_gettime-sys_poll

sys_clock_gettime-sys_poll-sys_poll-sys_socketcall

sys_poll-sys_socketcall-sys_poll-sys_clock_gettime

sys_poll-sys_clock_gettime-sys_clock_gettime-sys_clock_gettime

sys_clock_gettime-sys_clock_gettime-sys_socketcall-sys_clock_gettime

sys_socketcall-sys_clock_gettime-sys_poll-sys_poll

sys_poll-sys_poll

i'm using '-' as separator on comparing these phrases with the new traces, so i joined unique system calls with '-'.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far. If you get stuck, we'll try to help.

Comment: Question shows no effort at all. -1

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly it is that your length criterium specifies? All your example strings are of length > 4, so that would mean all strings are selected right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your desired words are divided by space. In that case just read your file line by line, and then get your words using `String.split(" ")`.
Here is the one i might think of:

```
public class FileSplitter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("input_file.txt");
        LinkedList<String> words = new LinkedList<String>();
        int i = 0;

        Files.lines(file.toPath()).
        forEachOrdered(line -> words.
                addAll(Arrays.asList(line.split(" "))));

        for(String word:words){
            if(word.trim().length() > 0){
                System.out.print(word.trim() + " ");
                if(i++ >= 3){
                    System.out.println();
                    i = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For your example it returns this:

```
sys_clock_gettime sys_poll sys_poll sys_clock_gettime 
sys_poll sys_poll sys_poll sys_clock_gettime 
sys_poll sys_clock_gettime sys_poll sys_poll 
sys_poll sys_poll sys_poll sys_poll
sys_poll sys_poll sys_socketcall
```

Comment: This is example of Java 8 usage. `line` here is a separate line from file as `String`.

Comment: I did not quite understand what you need to have but i am sure you could try it out with `String.split()` to extract required items from file and then count number of anything you want - symbols, words or anything else. Good luck